# Interesting Property of a simple algebraic cyclic identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across a simple result as follows:

If $ ax + b = bx + c = cx + a $ , 
then $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca = 0 $ , 
which implies $ a = b = c $, if $ a, b, c $ are real

Simply getting $ x $ from the first pair and then getting $ x $ from the second pair, and equating the results. (some cross multiplication and elementary algebra)

The result holds even if we slightly modify the identity as in:

$ ax + mb = bx + mc = cx + ma $

or

$ Max + b = Mbx + c = Mcx + a $

I am wondering if there are any useful applications of this result that comes to anyone's mind?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question about useful applications, but we can express your observation as: If
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 & 0 \\
0 & x & 1 \\
1 & 0 & x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}k\\k\\k\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $-1\ne x\in\Bbb R$, then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}r\\r\\r\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $r$. (In this case, $r=k/(x+1+0)$).

More generally, if $A$ is a nonsingular [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) and $\mathbf d$ denotes the vector $(1,\dots,1)$, then the equation $A\mathbf x=k\mathbf d$ has unique solution $\mathbf x=(k/\lambda)\mathbf d$, where $\lambda$ is the sum of the entries in a row of $A$. This follows from the fact that $\mathbf d$ is an eigenvector of every circulant matrix, with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Can't upvote it yet, but I like the answer. Thanks.